# Rotation Invariant Number Recognition

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have videos of tagged bees I would like to track. I can get the tag coordinates and the tag color, but I can not reliably get the numbers on the tags.

[image]

I can extract a tag and get an image like this:

[image]

But still I have trouble recognizing the number. I am using Python and OpenCV. I have tried Tesseract, but haven't had any success. The rotation of the tags are arbitrary, which is a major problem. Also, I am not sure if it is possible to distinguish 66 from 99 by looking at the tag only.

So, what is the best way to get the numbers on the tags?

Comment: "distinguish 66 from 99" -- how do the humans do it? Got some sample images of the whole set of tags? What do the single digit ones look like?

Comment: I guess it is guaranteed that there is space between 2 digits so you can just rotate image until you meet condition that you can fit white vertical line between them

Comment: @DanMašek The humans look at the bee as reference. Might be tricky for computers.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. That makes a lot of sense. I'm afraid the space might be too narrow in some cases (the 30 in the image), and single digits unfortunately do not have a leading zero.

Comment: @ovunctuzel So there's some standard way on how the tags are aligned on the bee's body? It's not very evident on the example photo (the yellow seems to be rotate 90 degrees, compared to the relative orientation of the white). In some situations this sort of ambiguity is resolved by adding a small line above or below the digits.

Comment: @ovunctuzel For 2digits case you can erode image and that would increase the gap between digits.

Comment: @DanMašek Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a standard. The images are a part of another project which weren't taken with image processing in mind. I might consider leaving uncertain tags to human inspection.

Comment: One very naive method that could produce some results is just to rotate the image incrementally until you get some agreement on the numbers returned by tesseract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV function minAreaRect() fits a minimum area rectangle to the digits.

With the assumption of digit height is always greater than digit width, and the minimum fitting rectangle is always along the axis of the digits, I have obtained a rotation value. This seems to do the trick in most cases.